# NameError: global name 'Model' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I have a simple Django app where I want to define two tables in the database: `user` and `question`.

I have the following `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name):
        user = cls(name=name)
        return user


class Question(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, content, answer):
        question = cls(content=content, answer=answer)
        return user
```

In `/questions`, which is defined in `views.py`, I would like to display all objects of type `question`:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.db import models


def questions(request):
    questions = Model.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM questions')
    return render_to_response('questions.html', questions)
```

However, I am getting:

```
NameError: global name 'Model' is not defined
```

Why is the `Model` object visible in `models.py` but not in `views.py`?

Also, is the way in which I query the database correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer to the question

`Model` is **not** visible in `models.py` - it's accessed as `models.Model`.

You're importing `models` but trying to use `Model` instead of `models.Model`.

Try this:

```
def questions(request):
    questions = models.Model.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM questions')
    return render_to_response('questions.html', questions)
```

Alternatively you can import `Model` directly:

```
from django.db.models import Model
```

## Answer to the problem

I think this is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

What you really want to do is access all instances of the `Question` model. If you want to use function based views for some reason, you can import the `Question` model and use it directly with `.all()`:

### Function based views

#### question/views.py

```
from myapp.models import Question

def questions(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('questions.html', questions)
```

### Class based views

The better option however, is to use a [class based generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/).
An example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects):

#### questions/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from questions.models import Question

class QuestionList(ListView):
    model = Question
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from questions.views import QuestionList

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^questions/$', QuestionList.as_view()),
]
```

Class based views offer much bigger expressiveness than funciton based viwes. They also eliminate the need for a lot of code duplication since commonly changed parts of a view can be overridden individually (e.g. `get_context_data`)

Comment: Possibly add: It's _not_ visible in `models.py` - it's accessed as `models.Model` there.

Comment: If I add this code `from models import Question` to `views.py` I get: `RuntimeError: Model class smartQuiz.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`. Any idea of what could cause this?

Comment: did you add your application smartQuiz to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your model in the following way inside your view

```
from myapp.models import Question

def questions(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('questions.html', questions)
```

for more information read the official documentation about views... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/